# Trying to use apache2 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: permissions, apache2

(I am new to Ubuntu/Linux so please bear with me).

I installed apache 2 (version 2.4.18) on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I did this from a logged in user account using

> sudo apt install apache2

Now, I am trying to replace the default index.html

However , I am unable to create or copy or move documents to

/var/www/html/

because I am not the owner of the folder 
I looked at the folder properties and it says the owner is root.

How do I change privileges so that I can use the apache server as if I (ie. the logged in user) had root-level privileges.

Thanks and happy new year.

Comment: use command `sudo chown currentusername:currentusername /var/www/html`

Comment: also you can do it by opening filemanager by root by issuing command `sudo nautilus` and after going into directory /var/www/ right click `html folder` and in properties you can change the owner

Answer (score 2):

The default user for *apache* is `www-data`, so this is how I did mine:

1. Add yourself to apache group `www-data`:

   ```
   sudo usermod -G www-data -a your_username
   ```
2. Change `/var/www/html` ownership:

   ```
   sudo chown -R your_username:www-data /var/www/html
   ```
3. Change the permissions on `/var/www/html`:

   ```
   sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/html
   ```

This way both *you and apache* can work with the *server documents* in `/var/www/html`

Answer (score 1):

use command `sudo chown currentusername:currentusername /var/www/html`

also you can do it by opening filemanager by root by issuing command `sudo nautilus` and after going into directory /var/www/ right click `html folder` and in properties you can change the owner